Building GCC 12.4, I get: libisl.so.23: ... No such file or directory
I'm trying to build GCC 12.4.0 on Oracle Linux 9.4 (sorry about that... not my choice of distribution), as a non-root user. So, I've downloaded and built my relevant prerequisites: gmp, mpfr, mpc, isl, installing them into their own separate directories. I now try:
./configure --disable-ada --disable-gnat --disable-fortran --disable-bootstrap \
    --disable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++  \
    --prefix=$HOME/opt/versions/gcc/12.4.0 --with-gmp=$HOME/opt/gmp \
    --with-mpfr=$HOME/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=$HOME/opt/mpc --with-isl=$HOME/opt/isl

but this gives me:
--- snip ---
/home/lh156516/src/gcc/gcc-12.4.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/home/lh156516/src/gcc/gcc-12.4.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/ -xc -nostdinc /dev/null -S -o /dev/null -fself-test=../.././gcc/testsuite/selftests
/home/lh156516/src/gcc/gcc-12.4.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/home/lh156516/src/gcc/gcc-12.4.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/ -xc++ -nostdinc /dev/null -S -o /dev/null -fself-test=../.././gcc/testsuite/selftests
/home/lh156516/src/gcc/gcc-12.4.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/cc1: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [../.././gcc/c/Make-lang.in:128: s-selftest-c] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/lh156516/src/gcc/gcc-12.4.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [../.././gcc/cp/Make-lang.in:206: s-selftest-c++] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4619: all-gcc] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1034: all] Error 2

All of the prerequisite libraries have been built and installed to their specified ~/opt subdirectories, and I've verified that I indeed have $HOME/opt/isl/lib/libisl.so.23. So, why am I getting this error?

have you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH accordingly? Built and installed the shared libraries to your prefix?

@MarcusMüller: I built and installed the libraries to those prefixes, yes; but - I did not add anything to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, assuming that if I specify the directory for the configure script it will make sure the build looks for the libraries there. Should I set it? ... but - I mis-copy-pasted the error into my title, so note the title change to match the error in the body of the question.

The title says ibisl.so.23 (missing initial 'l'), whereas the error output says libisl.so.23. Is there still a typo in the title?

The error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.23 is from the cc1 and cc1plus executables, rather than the linker. So, as Marcus already suggested is the problem that LD_LIBRARY_PATH hasn't been set? What is the output of ldd /home/lh156516/src/gcc/gcc-12.4.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/cc1?

@ChesterGillon: Fixed. Mi brein ys brken, I guess. As for LD_LIBRARY_PATH - when I'm back at that machine I'll try setting it to cover $HOME/opt/isl/lib/, and also provide the ldd output. Thanks :-)
